# Math function to filter negative numbers

Tags: function, math, negative-number

Is there any standard math function for this operation:

```
f(x)=max(x,0)
```

I was wondering maybe there is a well-known function for this operation in mathematics literature.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually denoted as (x)<sub>+</sub>, sometimes also x⊔0 or x∨0, where the symbol alludes to the shape of the kinks in the maximum of two functions, for instance in |x|=max(x,-x).

In Lebesgue integration theory, for example, a function is first split into its positive and negative part, so that the integration theory can be reduced to non-negative functions.

Another application is splines, the cubic B-spline has the representation

> B<sub>3</sub>(x)=1/6 * ( (x+2)<sub>+</sub><sup>3</sup> - 4 * (x+1)<sub>+</sub><sup>3</sup> + 6 * (x)<sub>+</sub><sup>3</sup> - 4 * (x-1)<sub>+</sub><sup>3</sup> + (x-2)<sub>+</sub><sup>3</sup> )

Comment: Please could you provide reference to where is this syntax used in? I am unable to find such syntax used in several Lebesgue integration articles. Could you advise?

Comment: The decomposition f=f_+-f_- should be standard in all text books on measure theory and integration. Perhaps not so much in research articles on Lebesgue integration, where these fundamentals are taken as granted. The other symbolism, x∨0, I have only seen in stochastics, martingale theory to be precisely. I think it is a standard notation in stopped processes, but there more often in its inverted form for the minimum.

Comment: Thanks. It is clear now.
If I understood it properly, we could say:
|x| = x∨-x

Comment: It exists as both. In the treatment of KKT systems I have seen it often as operator, for instance one NCP function (Evtushenko?) is 2ab-(a+b)_+^2.

Comment: Yes. But more often one will see t∧τ for min(t,τ), time t stopped at τ, see e.g., https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optional_stopping_theorem

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32137/i-there-some-common-abbreviation-for-minimum-in-equations

Answer (score 1):

I guess, you are looking for:

```
(abs(x)+x)/2
```

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%7Cx%7C%2Bx%29%2F2

Comment: Thank you Zlatin. But I was looking for a standard well-know function (if it exists). The expression that you suggested has the same result, but it's not a single function.

Comment: Please could you elaborate what do you mean by single function? In math terms it is a single function f(x)=(|x|+x)/2. I am not sure what do you mean.

Comment: I mean something like abs function whose definition is like

`f(x)<=x if x>=0 otherwise f(x)<=-x`.

In my case it's like

`f(x)<=x if x>=0 otherwise f(x)<=0`.

Comment: Nothing similar that I am aware of. In general, what you have written is classified as a conditional or piecewise function. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise

Answer (score 1):

Another way it might be characterised is as

```
x H(x)
```

where `H(x)` is the [Heaviside unit step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function).

```
H(x) = ( x >= 0 ? 1 : 0 )
```

i.e. 1 for positive x, 0 for negative x and either 0, 1, or 1/2 at x=0. This is used in control theory, signal processing and Fourier analysis. Its quite common to use f(x) H(x) for functions which start at a particular time, say switching some electronics on. So in this area of study `x H(x)` might be the best way to answer your question.